# Excel or Google forms - How to identify a specific cell on a table and update value from another worksheet data

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 2 work sheets. Sheet 2 has a table to be updated by the data from Sheet1. Sheet 2 first row has dates from today to 31 days and First column has names. Sheet1 has data columns of, Name, Shift (Give away, Swap, Delete, Take), Date, Letter( Which gives a letter as per Shift column entry. G - Give away, S- Swap, D- Delete, A - Take). What I need is a formula or a script to update Sheet2 by identifying the particular cell on sheet 2 by name and date from the Sheet 1 and enter the value from Letter column.

Sheet 1

```
Name | Shift.....| Date....| Letter..|    
Mark | Swap      |  02/AUG | S       |    
Ivon | Give away | 25/ AUG | G       |    
Laura| Take      | 01/AUG  | A       |     
Ann  | Take      | 02/AUG  | A       |    
Ann  | Give away | 03/AUG  | G       |
```

Sheet 2

```
|Name|01/AUG| 02/AUG | 03/AUG|....| 25AUG|

Laura| A    | < - if Laura has is available to Take a shift on 01AUG

Mark |      | 

Ann  |      | A      | G      | <- If Ann has is available to Take a shift on 02AUG and Give away shift on 03AUG

Ivon |
```

Comment: `What I need is a formula or a script` show what you have so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula you want is something like this:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$D$2:$D$6,MATCH(1,INDEX(($A2=Sheet1!$A$2:$A$6)*(Sheet1!$C$2:$C$6=B$1),),0)),"")
```

Put this in B2 copy over and down.

[image]

Comment: :) Thanks Scott.. you are awesome... This is what exactly I wanted.

Comment: One last help I need from you mate.. E.g. Ann has a Give away on 3AUG. now she wanted to Delete that entry. There for she makes an entry on Sheet1 for Delete. Ann| Delete| 03/AUG| D.  If this happens, I need to delete both the Delete entry and the previous Give away entry on Sheet 1. In case the delete entry was done by mistake and there is no Shift entry on particular date on the sheet 1, this delete shift should be deleted automatically on the same sheet1 and those entries will get cleared from the Sheet 2.

Comment: I am trying to use this script  as sheet 1 is a google Form resoponse sheet. and column A is Timestamp. I am trying to match column B which are names and Column D has the Dates. Basically If I find a match of name and date has been duplicated, I want both the entries to be deleted. But it is not working properly

Comment: I don't do google script sorry.  You should ask a new question with those tags and someone else with experience may be able to help.  be sure to post what you have tried.